# Windows 8.1 VPN error 800 when connecting to Mikrotik VPN router

Tags: vpn, windows-8.1, mikrotik

After creating a new VPN connection on a Windows 8.1 machine, to a VPN server (using Mikrotik router), the connection times out and an error no 800 is displayed.

Comment: Please post your answer as an answer, not as part of your question.

Answer (score 1):

[Mladen B.](https://serverfault.com/users/206869/mladen-b) answered his own question:

> Digging on the Mikrotik forum I [found a post](https://serverfault.com/users/206869/mladen-b) which resolves this
>   issue. Shortly, open the registry and navigate to the entry:
>   `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL`
>
> There, create a new DWORD key named `SendExtraRecord` with a Hex value
>   of `2`.After that retry the VPN connection (no need for a restart).
>
> *I just wanted to share this finding, since it is a very common and the page where the solution can be found is not very well optimized
>   for search engines, so I'll just leave it here for people to easier
>   solve it, if they encounter it.*
>
> [1](https://serverfault.com/users/206869/mladen-b): http://forum.mikrotik.com/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=78076

Answer (score 0):

I found a tutorial about fixing vpn error 800 in windows 7, windows 8,windows 8.1 on this website [I Trick Buzz](http://www.itrickbuzz.com/)

How to fix Error 800 Vpn windows 8.1

- Try pinging the server to make sure it is reachable.
- Check VPN IP address and VPN username password.
- Check firewall and router settings.

Source : How to fix [VPN Error 800](http://www.itrickbuzz.com/vpn-error-800-windows-7-8-8-1/) in windows 8.1